# Почему кнопка не видит функции моего скрипта Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

[image: не видит функцию]Здравствуйте. Я создал кнопку и повесил на неё скрипт. Кнопка не видит функцию из моего скрипта. Модификатор доступа у функции стоит public. Что мне делать?введите сюда описание изображения

```
    {
        isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && jumpsCount > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;
            jumpsCount--;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && jumpsCount == 0 && isGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;
        }

        if (isGround)
        {
            jumpsCount = jumpsValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Под разделителем должно быть имя вашего скрипта, но его там нет :). Либо он не на этом объекте, либо не скомпилировался, проверьте ошибки компиляции в консоли. Так же ваш скрипт должен наследовать от `MonoBehaviour` UPDATE: скрипт нужно вешать не на кнопку, а, в вашем случае, на объект `PlayerMove` - либо замените ссылку

Comment: PlayerMove это скрипт я его добавил к кнопке. Кнопка не видит функции скрипта.

Comment: Хм, а как вы его добавили? Присутствует ли он на сцене? Я подозреваю, что вы перетащили скрипт в поле объекта. Вместо этого нужно сделать так: добавьте скрипт объекту в качестве компонента (т.е. "повесьте" скрипт на объект в иерархии. На объект, который присутствует **на сцене**). А в поле объекта (в котором у вас сейчас скрипт) перетащите саму кнопку (т.е., объект, на котором висит ваш скрипт) из иерархии. В этом поле должен быть объект, который существует во время работы игры. Надеюсь, объяснил не очень путанно

Comment: Всё работает! Спасибо большое!

Comment: `PrtScr` это кнопка которая делает снимок экрана на компьютере, если не знали.